# Removing third dimension of matrix

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have matrix such that `A(:,:,1)=[1,2,3;2,3,4]`, `A(:,:,2)=[3,4,5;4,5,6]`.

How is the easiest way of accessing and plotting the vectors (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6). I tried creating `B=[A(:,:,1);A(:,:,2)]`, but i need a procedure to arbitrary number of A's.

Hope this isn't trivial and I've formulated myself satisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the order does not matter, here is how you can do it for vectors of length 3:

```
B = reshape(shiftdim(A,2), [], 3)
plot(B')
```

For vectors of arbitrary dimensions, replace 3 by `size(A,2)`

Answer (score 5):

You should think 'vertically'. This will allow you to use colon indexing:

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [1,2,3;2,3,4].'; %'// NOTE: transpose of your original
>> A(:,:,2) = [3,4,5;4,5,6].'; %'// NOTE: transpose of your original
>> A(:,:)
ans =
    1     2     3     4
    2     3     4     5
    3     4     5     6
```

The colon indexing with two colons works for any dimension `A`:

```
>> A(:,:,:,:,1,1) = [1 2 3; 2 3 4].';   %'
>> A(:,:,:,:,2,1) = [3 4 5; 4 5 6].';   %'
>> A(:,:,:,:,1,2) = [5 6 7; 6 7 8].';   %'
>> A(:,:,:,:,2,2) = [7 8 9; 8 9 0].';   %'
>> A(:,:)
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
```

Colon indexing in MATLAB is quite interesting and really powerful once you master it. For example,  if you use fewer colons than there are dimensions in the array (like above), MATLAB will automatically concatenate the remainder of the data along the dimension equal to the colon count.

So, if `A` has 48 dimensions, but you index with just 2 colons: you'll get a 2D array, that is the concatenation of the remaining 46 dimensions along the 2<sup>nd</sup>  dimension.

In general: if `A` has `N` dimensions, but you index with just `M ≤ N` colons: you'll get an `M`-D array, that is the concatenation of the remaining `N-M` dimensions along the `M`<sup>th</sup>  dimension.

So as long as you are free to define your `A` to contain vectors on the *columns* rather than the *rows* (you should advise everyone to do this, as virtually everything in MATLAB is a bit faster that way), I think this is the fastest and most elegant way to do what you want.

If not, well, then just `reshape` like Dan :)